# Are there Perl modules that can't be used in CGI?

Tags: perl, module, cgi

I had a recent problem where Tie::File proved the best answer I could work with for a Perl program. I'm at a point where I'm ready to work with CGI, and I need to ask: are there Perl modules that can't be used in CGI, especially that Tie::File? If there are any complications, are there ways to reconcile them?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A CGI is basically just a program that reads a request on STDIN and spews header + HTML on STDOUT. It isn't really special: there aren't any modules you can't use, if you try hard enough.

You could even get graphical (e.g., GTK) ones working with enough pain. Not that you'd want to. Unless you're a third-party vendor I've had the displeasure of making that work for.

But remember that multiple copies of your program may be running simultaneously (one per simultaneous web request), so if you're using flat files, you'll have to deal with locking.

Comment: That does help me a lot, but if you know, would there be any limitation to the Tie::File one? Right now I'm assuming that it should be fine, but if there are any problems I'll definitely need help figuring out what I need to do to make it work in CGI. Thank you very much.

Comment: No reason it shouldn't work provided it's available in the environment you're going to run the CGI in. Without looking at Tie::File, I'm confident that it's as simple as shipping it alongside your foo.cgi file in an appropriate library directory. Beter would be using CPAN to install it, of course.

Comment: Tie::File comes with perl, so it's going to be there. It should work fine *if you lock the file*.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your data file is readable *and* writable by your CGI process. I'm adding this answer because it led to a very odd bug. I had a script that wouldn't run from CGI. In fact the CGI could read the contents of the data just fine, but Tie::File failed (even though it worked fine if I called it from the command line). It turns out the permissions were set -rw-rw-r-- which means world-readable, but only my user and group could write to it. Since the CGI process didn't have write permissions, Tie::File failed in CGI.